# Override Python Library File to Circumvent Size Limitation

Tags: python

I ran into a 100 named capture group limitation in Python's regular expression named capture groups.

The hard-coded limitation is in sre_compile.py:

```
if p.pattern.groups > 100:
    raise AssertionError(
        "sorry, but this version only supports 100 named groups"
        )
```

My understanding is that this limitation is for performance reasons and not necessarily for space limitations. In my case the performance issues are less important than this capability. So I wonder if there is a reasonable way to get around this limitation? Possibly by injecting a replacement sre_compile.py file with the size check removed? Of course, this sounds quite risky and I understand that such an action is not recommended. However, in the short term I need to circumvent this limitation, in the long term I have a nice work around.  Any suggestions on the best solution?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: For completeness the solution worked as advertised but there was another hard coded limit in the C code itself.  I ended up using an alternate python regex package (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex/) which worked great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to mess with python's libraries, you can simply replace the function in your code:

```
import sre_compile

def my_compile(p, flags=0):
    ...

sre_compile.compile = my_compile
```

Comment: Wow, that's cool.  It had not occurred to me that this was possible, too much time working with java and c I suppose.  Well, the solution is right, but after trying it out it turns out the limitation must also be replicated in the underlying regex compiler (as the exception now comes from the c code).  Maybe I can switch out the compiler.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

try to download pycparse-2.14.tar.gz in https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pycparser/2.14
and run the command below

```
tar zxf pycparser-2.14.tar.gz
cd pycparser-2.14
python setup.py  install
```